# Same type of data once called is a JSON Object but when called 2nd time it turns out to be a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Following is my JS Code.

```
function showresult(data){
    jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
        var count = 1;
        if(key == 0){
            jQuery.each(value, function(key, value) {
                var str = value.split(',');
                jQuery.each(str, function(key, value1) {
                    eval("document.getElementById('image"+count+"').src = '"+value1+"';");
                    count++;
                });

            });
        }
        if(key == 1){
            var count = 1;
            jQuery.each(value, function(key, value) {
                jQuery.each(value, function(key, value1) {
                    jQuery('#image'+count).after(value1+'%');
                    count++;
                });

            });
        }
    });
}
```

When I do`alert(data)`, I get `[object Object]`, following is the data I am passing to the function.

```
[{"path":"patternimages/041929_d.jpg,patternimages/016630_d.jpg,patternimages/039462_d.jpg,patternimages/065862_d.jpg,patternimages/041984_d.jpg,patternimages/041931_d.jpg,patternimages/041939_d.jpg,patternimages/075066_d.jpg"},{"percentage":["100","100","99","98","98","97"]}]
```

When another call made to the same function but with different data, after `alert(data)` gives me following result. I was expecting `[object Object]` after alert but I didn't got that type of result after alert.

```
[{"path":"patternimages/051696_d.jpg,patternimages/026965_d.jpg,patternimages/047889_d.jpg,patternimages/050544_d.jpg,patternimages/019186_d.jpg,patternimages/005978_d.jpg,patternimages/044707_d.jpg,patternimages/045949_d.jpg,patternimages/104967_d.jpg,patternimages/006135_d.jpg,patternimages/006897_d.jpg,patternimages/017471_d.jpg"},{"percentage":["83","83","80","80","65","63","63","63","62","59","59","51"]}].
```

Following is my PHP Code

```
public function result($result) {
        $results = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id[] = $row['image_id'];
            $percentage[] = $row['percentage'];
        }
        if (@count($id) > 1) {
            $id = array_unique($id);
        } else {
            @$id = $id;
        }
        $fresult = $this->GetResult($id);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($fresult);
        if ($count > 1) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fresult)) {
                $ids[] = $row['id'];
                $names[] = $row['name'];
                $percentages[] = $row['percentage'];
            }
            $percent_val = array();
            $res = implode(',patternimages/', $names);
            $path['path'] = 'patternimages/' . $res;
            $percent_val['percentage'] = $percentages;
            array_push($results, $path);
            array_push($results, $percent_val);
        } else {
            $results = 'No Data Found';
        }

        return $results;
    }
```

the result is encoded to JSON response like this  `echo json_encode($results, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

EDIT JS code

```
  $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: url,
                        data: {color1: color1},
                        success: function(data) {
                            showresult(data);

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Where does the data come from for both the first and second calls?

Comment: @Teeg: its Actually Ajax/Json response that i fetch from server, i will place the script for that code too in my snippet

Comment: Why are you using `eval` for this?! And why mix jQuery and plain JS in such a fashion?

Comment: @DaveNewton: this may be strange , but it was strange for me too, i am actually modifying some 1 else's code, my part is mainly in Jquery and original code is in JS.

Comment: @noobie-php: Either way, get rid of the eval. It isn't needed and is terrible practice.

Comment: Where is the client-side code that actually calls this `showresult`? How are you making the AJAX calls to the server? Can you look in your browser's console and check the headers and see what type the response is claiming to be? Your actual `showresult` function isn't the problem and is probably irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @MattBurland: thx for the interest mate, i will for sure post the function that is calling the sub function.. Check my updated code

Comment: Some part of your code are ugly, e.g. `eval("document.getElementById('image"+count+"').src = '"+value1+"';");` Why not `jQuery("#image" + count).attr("src", value1)`?

Comment: @AnthonyGarcia: i guess u skipped all the way to the bottom, mate i already told that i am modifying some 1 else's code.